# Attaching an Event to an element and dispatching it correctly

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I need to attach an Event called `render` to a `panel` element, that does nothing but being dispatched to warn all the listeners whenever `panel` is rendering.

Following the The old-fashioned way section of [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), I came up with this code:

```
/**
* **Static** Re-draw the layer panel to represent the current state of the layers.
* @param {Element} panel The DOM Element into which the layer tree will be rendered
*/
static renderPanel(panel) {

    // Create the event.
    var render_event = document.createEvent('Event');

    // Define that the event name is 'render'.
    render_event.initEvent('render', true, true);

    // Listen for the event.
    panel.addEventListener('render', function (e) {
        // e.target matches panel
    }, false);

    panel.dispatchEvent(render_event);
```

This seems to have worked but as this is my first time doing this, I am not quite sure how to check the correctness of this method.

Looking inside the console I can see my `panel` element dispatching the `render` Event, but I'd like to ask if there's something I am missing or to be worried about before moving on.

To debug the result, I tried add an event listener to the `document` element like `document.addEventListener("render",console.log("ciao"))`, which in turn printed `ciao` once in the console, but only just once.

I thought I would be able to see as many "ciao" in the console as the times the `render` Event was triggered, but this does not seem the case.

[image]

Comment: [`.addEventListener(type, listener[, options])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) -> `listener`: _"The object which receives a notification (an object that implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the `EventListener` interface, or a **JavaScript function**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to check everytime your event is fired, the second argument of addEventListener (taking into account what you're willing to achieve) should be a function callback using an event object as argument, like this for example:

```
document.addEventListener("render", function(e) { console.log("ciao"); });
```

In your example you're executing console.log("ciao"), not passing a function reference (anonymous or not), this is why it executes only one time: when the page loads/evaluates your script.

Answer (score 1):

[mdn guide on creating and dispatching custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) (same as your link)

The old fashioned method seems to still be working fine when I tried it, I saw the document event listener console log each time I triggered the event.

The updated way is:
`panel.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('render'));`

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('old-event', () => {console.log('Old-fashinoed event caught')});
div.addEventListener('new-event', () => {console.log('New-fashioned event caught')});

let oldEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
oldEvent.initEvent('old-event', true, true);

let newEvent = new CustomEvent('new-event');

setInterval(() => {
  div.dispatchEvent(oldEvent);
  div.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>I emit an old-fashioned and a new-fashioned event every 1 second</div>
```

Comment: I tried to change the code in `static renderPanel(panel) {panel.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('render'));}` and then I tried to test it with `document.addEventListener("render", function(e) {console.log("ciao!");});` as @sed_lex suggested but it didn't show "ciao!" in the console, while the old-fashioned method did work. Using both firefox and Chrome console.

Comment: I decided to accept @sed_lex answer as it answered my question as to why I couldn't see "ciao" logged in the console more than once. Anyway, I really appreciate your suggestion to use the new way. My attempt was to keep IE compatibility.